# problems in prestashop-php log file

Tags: php, apache, prestashop, plesk

I am working with prestashop, everything works fine, except that in the error log, before the error description, the following text is always added:

`[Tue Nov 15 17:17:13.077035 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 22406:tid 140364891481856] [client xxx.xxx.xx.x:xxxx] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: Array\n(\n [ 0] => 16\n [1] => 14\n [2] => 13\n [3] => 12\n [4] => 11\n [5] => 10\n [6] => 9\n [7] => 8\n [8] => 4\n [9] => 5\n [10] => 6\n)\n\n', referer: /index.php ?controller=AdminOrders&token=9....`

This adds it to each record, so it is very difficult to read them. Could it be a php configuration problem? or will it be prestashop configuration.

thank you very much for your ideas.

Comment: I think someone who debugged the code forgot a 'var_dump' somewhere.... I would check in that way

Comment: It seems a debugging throwed error, if someone did something on your PrestaShop, maybe forgot to remove that.